# Having issues when migrating asm vm's into arm

Tags: powershell, azure

When am trying to migrate 2 vm's inside a vnet (ASM Deployment), I am getting an error on prepare statment I am running the simple command to migrate a vnet which contains 2 vms the commandc

```
$vnetName = "ASMTOARM"

Move-AzureVirtualNetwork -Prepare -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName
```

I am using the latest version of powershell, now the error which I am getting:-

```
Move-AzureVirtualNetwork : XrpVirtualNetworkMigrationerror. : Template DC-1-Template deployment failed.
CorrelationId=a273db43-6920-49a6-b6d5-45d91cbac676
At line:1 char:1
+ Move-AzureVirtualNetwork -Prepare -VirtualNetworkName $vnetName
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo         : CloseError: (:) [Move-AzureVirtualNetwork], ComputeCloudException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.Network.MoveVirtualNetworkCommand
```

Comment: Nobody can reproduce this error as we don't have access to your specific azure environment.

Comment: can you tell mE something about this error

Comment: Please show more error logs here, you can find the logs from Azure portal state.

Comment: Does it work now? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.